# Get google analytics id from the code embed?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

As an example, the code I have to embed has an ID of the form: `UA-3235632-1`, but to use the data export API I need the ID from the URL of the proper page, in this case: `6270018`.

How do I get the real ID from the UA type ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That feature of the the GA Data Export API could indeed be a little more clear.

Here's what you need to do:

1. login to the GA Browser and in the
   upper-right-hand corner drop-down
   menu, select your GA Account of
   interest (assuming you have more
   than one--if you don't then you are
   already on right page). The page
   that renders will be the *Website
   Profiles* for that Account. Find the
   row in that table that corresponds
   to the Profile (Report) you want
   retrieve data from and click on the
   next-to-last column *Edit*;
2. The page you'll see now will say
   *Profile Settings* in the upper
   left-hand corner. Just under that,
   in smaller font, you'll see ***Profile
   ID*** followed by a string of digits
   (probably six to eight). This is what you want
   (in the python client for the GA
   Data Export API, it is referred to
   as TABLE_ID)).

To retrieve this parameter (TABLE_ID) programmatically, the GA Data Export API **Account Feed** returns this value to you in the ***dxp:tableID field***. In particular, an Account Query will return the *list of profiles* under that Account to which you have access; each Profile will have a tableID in the field i mentioned just above.

Comment: OK, got that, but can I get it programmatically?

Comment: supplementing my answer above to include an answer to your follow-up Q