# Google Analytics API: filter by URI?

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-api, google-analytics-api

My site has user profiles that are accessible via URLs that look like this: `www.domain.com/profile/123/...`. I want to show users page view statistics of their profiles, but need to be able to do wildcards.

For example, this works:

```
filters=ga:pagePath==/profile/123/
```

The problem is that there are potentially other URI segments that follow `/profile/123/`. I want to do something like this (does not work):

```
filters=ga:pagePath==/profile/123/*
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the 'Contains a match for the regular expression' operator (~) from the [Dimension Filters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterSyntax).

```
filters=ga:pagePath=~/profile/123/*
```

Comment: @yahelc, The #~ is correct but * doesn't mean what you think in regular expressions.  In fact filters=ga:pagePath=~/profile/123/ is sufficient in this case.

Comment: I left the original double `==` in my query and was confused as to why it wasn't working...essentially: `filters=ga:pagePath==~/profile/123/*` >___<

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
 filters=ga:pagePath=~/profile/123/
```

To do `/*/view/*` (as per @VinnyG’s comment), this should work:

```
filters=ga:pagePath=~/[^/]+/view/
```

I'm assuming you want to match one (and only one) directory before `/view/`.

Answer (score 1):

Another filter from the Dimension Filters that would work for you is `contains "=@"`

`ga:pagePath=@/profile/123`

Answer (score 0):

worked for me.

```
    
    require('gapi.class.php');
    $ga = new gapi('mail@example.com','google_analytics_password');
    $filter = 'ga:pagePath==/home.php';

    //first parameter is your Google Analytics profile id

    /* How to find Google Analytics Profile ID
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119610/get-google-analytics-id-from-the-code-embed/4120625#4120625
    */
    $ga->requestReportData(0000000,array('pagePath'),array('pageViews','UniquePageviews'), '-pageViews', $filter);

    foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
    {
        echo $result->getPageviews();
        echo $result->getUniquePageviews();
        echo $result->getPagePath();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: GAPI Class (Google Analytics PHP Interface)
http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

Comment: How to find Google Analytics Profile ID 
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119610/get-google-analytics-id-from-the-code-embed/4120625#4120625